# Classes for class diagram UML

Tags: uml, class-diagram, class-design

I am currently studying an example [from an online course](https://www.educative.io/courses/grokking-the-object-oriented-design-interview/RMlM3NgjAyR#Activity-diagrams) to design a class diagram for a Library Management System.

However, I am confused with this example: [image]

I can't really understand the purpose of creating two classes: `Book` and `Book Item`.
Couldn‘t I just insert attributes from `Book Item` class into the `Book` class and keep only a single class of the two?

Comment: The `Extends` label is futile. It's only there to suit Java coders but UML-wise it is here of no use.

Comment: Also the UC diagram in the link you used is just wrong in some aspects. Arrows for extend/include are wrong. Login is no use case. Placing `System` as actor outside the boundary is - no words...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting example:

- The `Book` refers to an book in the catalogue of the publisher or the library. It has an ISBN to uniquely identify it, a title, an author and so on.
- The `BookItem` refers to a copy of that book that is owned by the the library and is lend to the users.

But this example requires improvements:

- the model should prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)., which in UML translates tonprefering a simple association over a specialization. Several `BookItems` may refer to the same `Book`, and the model does not capture this reality.
- The boundaries between book and book items need to be reviewed. For example the BookFormat (only in item) may in reality influence the number of pages (in book). Moreover a publishing date seems not to be specific to a book item but general to the book. Printing date could change on each item.

Comment: They even made Book an abstract class, which it clearly shouldn't be. The fact that this is an example from an actual UML course is just sad.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Indeed, this is poor course material. On the other side,  nobody can claim for a refund, since its free ;-)

Comment: Currently reading the OO book from Meyer (the Eiffel guy). He explains in long and broad what inheritance should mean. I just remember where he picked one of the many bad examples: ApplePie inheriting from Apple and Pie (argh!) and Plane inherinting from VentilationSystem. As for the latter: if the crew welcomes me with "Welcome aboard our ventilation systen" I would probably run.

Comment: I would not call the a above _interesting_. **Strange** would be more a suitable description.

Comment: @qwerty_so Thank you for the answers! Could you please recommend a book or website with good examples? At this point it's overwhelming to see which diagrams are correctly implemented

Comment: That's a tough one. I once approached it via the ICONIX methodology which really got me going. I came along with a (affordable) example and video explanation (by Dough Rosenberg). That's almost 20 years ago. The "bible" UML 2.5 spec is unfortunately not for a bed lecture. Google fort uml-diagrams.org which have a quite nice overview and examples. A few of it outdated but it's not the worst (at least better than the site you cited). The book from Meyer is quite expensive and does not use current UML notation. Unless you will learn Eiffel or are in compiler construction I would not recommend it.

Comment: @qrttttt Martin Fowler‘s book *UML distilled* is still a very good introduction to most aspects of UML. It has plenty of rather relevant examples. There is the *UML user guide* as well. It‘s more in depth but it‘s a lot more thicker. It has the advantage of being written by the UML inventors and to uniquely describe the intent behind more advanced and kess understood modelling techniques.

Comment: @qwerty_so uml-diagrams.org seems to be offline, though it still appears when doing a Google search.

Comment: @carloswm85 https://www.uml-diagrams.org/ still works for me

Comment: @Christophe it looks like it was a momentary problem somewhere in the site connection. Thanks for the reply.